# How to render shadow only in cycles blender 3.0?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

This is what I want. One layer of object and one layer of shadow ?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

### Blender 3.1

Comes with [Shadow Catcher pass](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/render/layers/passes.html) :)

### Blender 3.0 or lower

- Add *Plane* and under *Object Properties > Visibility* enable **Shadow Catcher**
- Create a new *Collection* and move *Plane* into this collection
- Add a new *View Layer.001* and under *Filter* icon enable last two icons (**Holdout** for collection with Cube and **Indirect** for collection with Plane as shown on screen)

[image]

Set *Render Properties > Film >* **Transparent** and switch to *VFX > Composite* layout to mix Layers together ...

[image]
(or you can use compositor  to let blender know to save View Layers as separate files)

I used 2.8x ... but system is the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't work. Now I lost the shadows.

Comment: Sorry I have to leave now ... have you checked my blend file? If you dont discover mistake by your self, attach your fimplifed blend to your Q so someone can help. Like now your comment is useless.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see your file before. I watch youtube tutorials all afternoon. I will check your file.  Thanks